# How to get each user of save preferences instead Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to display each user that played a quiz with its score. like `[{nome: to, score: 1}, {nome: hjk, score: 1}]`  but now when I use `final a = share.read('pessoas'); print('soul $a');` it displays `Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'` here is how my code is doing:

```
read(String key) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    Map<String, dynamic> userMap;
    final String userStr = await prefs.getString("pessoas");

    if (userStr != null) {
      //final Pessoas user = await Pessoas.fromJson(userMap);
      print(json.decode(userStr));
      return json.decode(userStr);
    }
    //return null;
    //return json.decode(prefs.getString(key));
  }
```

Comment: Could you provide the code part where you are using `final a = share.read('pessoas');`? At the first sight, it seems that you are missing an `await` before `share.read('pessoas');`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign the future to final a.

If you want to assign the value that is returned from the future, you have to await the future to give back a response, which it then assigns to final a as followed:

```
final a = await share.read('pessoas');
```

Answer (score 0):

from your question, seems you are missing the await thus,

```
final a = await share.read('pessoas');
print('soul $a');
```